# WPFToolkit AutoComplete, styling the textbox & dropdown list

Tags: wpf, styles, wpftoolkit, datatrigger, autocompletebox

I have the following code creating a AutoCompleteBox (using WPFToolkit) that combines Companies and Employees into a single search feature.  I am forced to use an ObservableCollection as the AutoCompleteBox does not know how to handle CompositeCollections (at least according to what I could find on the subject).

I would like to style the dropdown and textbox such that a Company's text is red and an Employee's text is green.  I can set the text color for the entire dropdown as shown in the ResourceDictionary below but cannot find a way to use the DataTrigger (what I have below does not work).

I am not sure how to Bind the DataTrigger to the ModelType property of each object in SearchCollection.

**EDIT:**

After looking at the code again I realize that there is not a Property called ModelType exposed in the VM, the ModelType property is on each of the objects in SearchCollection.  How can I bind to the ModelType of each object in the collection?

In XAML:

```
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="OmniSearchTextBox"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding SearchCollection}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding Selection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
                             KeyUp="OmniSearch_KeyUp"
                             MouseLeftButtonUp="OmniSearch_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                             IsTextCompletionEnabled="False" 
                             FilterMode="Contains" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0" >
```

In VM:

```
public sealed class SearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private ViewModelLocator _vmLocator;
    private ObservableCollection<Company> _companyList;
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employeeList;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the SearchViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public SearchViewModel()
    {
        try
        {
            _vmLocator = new ViewModelLocator();


            _searchCompCollection.Add(companies);
            _searchCompCollection.Add(employees);


            foreach (Company co in CompanyList)
            {
                _searchCollection.Add(co);
            }


            foreach (Employee emp in EmployeeList)
            {
                _searchCollection.Add(emp);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }


    private const string CompanyListPropertyName = "CompanyList";
    public ObservableCollection<Company> CompanyList
    {
        get
        {
            return (_vmLocator.CompanyVM).CompanyList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_companyList == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _companyList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CompanyListPropertyName);
        }

    }


    private const string EmployeeListPropertyName = "EmployeeList";
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeList
    {
        get 
        {
            return (_vmLocator.EmployeeVM).EmployeeList;  
        }
        set
        {
            if (_employeeList == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _employeeList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(EmployeeListPropertyName);
        }

    }



    private ObservableCollection<ModelBase> _searchCollection = new ObservableCollection<ModelBase>();
    public ObservableCollection<ModelBase> SearchCollection
    {
        get { return _searchCollection; }
    }


    private string _selection = null;
    private string _origSelection = null;
    public string Selection
    {
        get
        {
            return _selection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selection != value)
            {
                _origSelection = _selection;
                _selection = value;
                try
                {
                    var item = _searchCollection.Single<Object>(x => x.ToString() == _selection);
                    this.SelectedObject = item;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private object _selectedObject = null;
    private object _origSelectedObject = null;
    public object SelectedObject
    {
        get { 
            return _selectedObject; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedObject != value)
            {
                _origSelectedObject = _selectedObject;
                _selectedObject = value;

                switch(_selectedObject.GetType().BaseType.Name)
                {
                    case "Company":
                        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedObject", 
                                             (Company)_origSelectedObject, 
                                             (Company)_selectedObject, 
                                             true);
                        break;

                    case "Employee":
                        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedObject",
                                             (Employee)_origSelectedObject,
                                             (Employee)_selectedObject,
                                             true);

                        break;

                    default:

                        break;
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedObject", _origSelectedObject, _selectedObject, true);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In ResourceDictionary (ModelType is a property available in each Model that simply returns the class type, i.e., Company or Employee):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:AutoCompleteBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkCyan" /> 
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SearchCollection.ModelType}" 
                     Value="Company">  
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SearchCollection.ModelType}" 
                     Value="Employee">  
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>  
</Style>
```

Comment: You should be able to bind to your `ModelType` property just using `{Binding ModelType}`, but you have further problems with your `DataTrigger`. I believe that you are trying to set the `Foreground` property of each line in the drop down, but you are actually setting the `Foreground` property of the whole `AutoCompleteBox` control.

Comment: @Sheridan The code I have posted does set the Text color of the drop down and the text box, but currently it is all set to DarkCyan (via the first setter property).  What I cannot get to work is the DataTrigger to set the text color based on the ModelType.

Comment: As I said, you are setting the `Foreground` property of the whole AutoCompleteBox control. This won't do what you want and the only way that I can think of is for you to create your own `AutoCompleteTextBox` (which doesn't take that long).